# How close can a drone be to a wind turbine in Germany?

Tags: regulations, fixed-wing, safety, distance-limit

I operate a rather professional fixed wing drone which requires pre-flight planning via an app and doesn't support direct control besides instant flight abortion and "return to landing zone" command.

Due to the fixed wings the covering of an area of interest includes U-turns at the end of each pass. These U-turns make things a bit complicated when it comes to flight planning, since they "collide" with a wind turbine. I was wondering, how much distance I have to keep. My location is Germany.

Flying above the obstacle is no option, since the drone is only registered in the open category, hence the maximum flight level is 120 m above ground.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

very intersting question
I am in your situation as well flying LOS of course: in the EU assuming you are operating an A3 Open Category UAS, according to EASA, we should keep the drone (fixed wing or rotary doesen't matter) 150 mt away from build up areas.
The D-flight site will provide additional limitation for the area you are operating. Please be sure to register your flight before flying.

[image: Please see the EASA slide attached, Enjoy and fly safe]

Comment: I was under the impression, that a registered drone and a certified pilot (license becomes outdated next year, but I need to refresh anyways) wont need to register the specific flight when not in the vincinity of any airport/landingstrip/etc. But that is another question.

Comment: Hi Mate thanks for your comment, please read the document 'COMMISSION IMPLEMENTING REGULATION (EU) 2021/664 of 22 April 2021 on a regulatory framework for the U-space' https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX%3A32021R0664&qid=1636039356532 that as far I understand applies to your UAS in Germany. All the best